# AVI INFO crashes the Octave GUI every time I try to run the code

Tags: ffmpeg, octave, codec, avi

I am trying to run a code in octave which requires reading frame info of a video file. However, it always crashes when I write the `aviinfo`. The line goes as this:

```
> vInfo = aviinfo('C:\devwork\Octave\boosted\resizedVideos\11-50-48--11-50-58_resized.mp4');
```

I realized that I did not have FFmpeg installed on my system. I did install it but still it crashes. Any idea why? How should I solve it?

While looking for solutions I came across [this discussion](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/octave-video-avi-crashes-anybody-have-similar-experience-td2309258.html) which says there is a possibility of an "unfortunate interplay between the Octave code and the ffmpeg code. But I am unable to figure out why?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of octave did you install.

Newer versions (latest is 4.2.1) all include the video package with ffmpeg preinstalled, so should be just a matter of loading the video package and then running the command.

For the above example, you are trying to read an avi file, not write it, so if the file does not exist there may be issues.

Running a similar example on my win10 machine using the video package, I see the same issue of it crashing.

It is now reported as an issue in an octave bug report: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?51057

Comment: I have installed Octave 4.2.1 (the latest one). I am able to use the command `aviread ( filename , N )` for loading the frame. However, as soon as I load `aviinfo`, it crashes. But apparently, this is happening on windows. I asked a friend to do it on Mac and he was able load the `aviinfo` command successfully.

Comment: @Sulphur: You can download the version with Johns patch from the patchtracker and install it with "pkg install ....". Or wait until the fixed release is available via "-forge"